VBA read sharepoint list - unauthorized error on file re-open
I've been writing vba for over 5  years now and today I'm stuck with an issue that's mind boggling. I tried hours of research and GenAI tools. Nothing is able to solve the problem. Basically I'm reading a sharepoint list to look for a file and compare it's publish date to the one within my file. The funny thing is. The code runs absolutely fine and does the job. However, here's when things become SUPER WIERD!
1.) if you have another excel open(File B). Run the macro (A). It works. Close the macro and re-open and run again, it still works.
2.) run the macro, close all excels and open this macro and run it again you start getting a 401 error code. Funnily on the web I'm not asked to re-authenticate my self. This macro is now useless. you'll never get past the 401 code unless:
3) save As the file from the UI( you can even replace it with the same name). Now run the macro and viola works again. Now next super wierd issue
4) I tried programatically doing a save as. Does not work. I tried using VBA to mimic the UI save AS to display the box and then save. STILL DOES NOT WORK but if you manually save as from the UI. Code runs again with 200 success.
Wierdest issue I'm facing after having written million of lines of VBA in all these years. Someone who can crack this for me has all my respect!
Here's the code: (Just download a JSON converter bas file online). For the purposes of testing you dont even need to go past the response code line to be honest.
Note: you can change the url to a free sharepoint list online since you will not have access to this link. I've scrubbed the url since its my company site but kept all parameters so you know how I built the url fully.
Sub GetSharePointListDataAndCompare()
Dim xml As Object
Dim url As String
Dim json As Object
Dim item As Object
Dim publishDate As Date
Dim name As String
Dim namedPublishDate As Date
Dim namedName As String
Dim isMatch As Boolean
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cookies As String
Dim cookieRange As Range

'RenameAndSaveWorkbook
'SimulateManualSaveAs

'RefreshWorkbook

' Set the URL to the SharePoint list REST API endpoint with specific fields
url = "https://sharepoint.com/sites/Tax/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('crc')/items?$select=ID,Title,LinkFilename,CandC_PublishedDate"

' Create XMLHTTP object
Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

' Check if the named range "cookie" exists and is not blank
On Error Resume Next
Set cookieRange = ThisWorkbook.Names("cookie").RefersToRange
On Error GoTo 0

If Not cookieRange Is Nothing Then
    cookies = cookieRange.Value
End If

' Open the connection to the URL
xml.Open "GET", url, False
xml.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose"

' Send the request
xml.send

' Check if the request was successful
If xml.Status = 200 Then
            
    ' Parse the JSON response
    Set json = ParseJson(xml.responseText)
    
    ' Get the named ranges values
    namedPublishDate = ThisWorkbook.Names("publishDate").RefersToRange.Value
    namedName = ThisWorkbook.Names("toolName").RefersToRange.Value
    
    ' Initialize match flag
    isMatch = False
    
    ' Iterate through the items and compare
    For Each item In json("d")("results")
        ' Convert SharePoint date to VBA date
        publishDate = CDate(Mid(item("CandC_PublishedDate"), 1, 10))
        name = item("LinkFilename")
        
        If name = namedName Then
            If publishDate > namedPublishDate Then
                isMatch = True
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next item
    
    ' Display the result
    If isMatch Then
        MsgBox "A newer publish date was found in the SharePoint list! Current: " & namedPublishDate & " New: " & publishDate
    Else
        MsgBox "No newer publish date found."
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "Error: " & xml.Status & " - " & xml.statusText
End If

' Clean up
Set xml = Nothing
Set json = Nothing
End Sub


Can't reproduce what you're seeing.  If I close Excel completely and re-open only the file with the code, it works fine.
